# UTF8 Character lost when written to file

Tags: c#, filestream

I am creating an application to scan and merge CSV files.  I am having an issue when writing the data to a new file.  One of the fields has the ö character which is maintained until i write it to the new file.  It then becomes the "actual" value: Ã¶ instead of the "expected" value: ö

I am suspecting that UTF8 Encoding is not the best thing to use but have yet to find a better working method.  Any help with this would be much appreciated!

```
byte[] nl = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("\n");
using (FileStream file = File.Create(filepath))
{
string text;
byte[] info;

for (int r = 0; r < data.Count; r++)
{
    int c = 0;
    for (; c < data[r].Count - 1; c++)
    {
        text = data[r][c] + @",";
        text = text.Replace("\n", @"");
        text = text.Replace(@"☼", @"""");

        info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
        file.Write(info, 0, text.Length);
    }

    text = data[r][c];
    info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
    file.Write(info, 0, text.Length);

    file.Write(nl, 0, nl.Length);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be mistaken and this should probably go in a comment but I can't comment yet. Text editors will decode the binary data into a certain encoding. You can check the actual binary data in a hex editor. You can verify the binary data you are writing out to the file. Notepad++ has a hex editor plug in that you could use.

[BinaryWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx)  is easier to work with when it comes to writing bytes to a file. you can also set the encoding of the BinaryWriter. You'll want to set this to UTF-8.

Edit

I forgot to mention. When you write out to bytes you are going to want to read in as bytes as well. Use [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the encoding to UTF-8.

Once you read the Bytes in use [Encoding.UTF8.GetString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the bytes into a string.

Comment: Why they throught giving a *binary* reader an encoding was an idea worth considering at all is beyond me...

Comment: Thanks.  You're right it's not this function at all it's the text editor.  Notepad++ clicked Encoding (think they could name it better, how am I supposed to know it's a menu about encoding?) and changed it to UTF8.  All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

You might be truncating the output since UTF-8 is multibyte.

Don't do this:

```
info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
file.Write(info, 0, text.Length);
```

Instead use `info.Length`.

```
info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
file.Write(info, 0, info.Length); // change this line
```

Comment: Yea I fixed that haha it would cut the comma off when this character would appear.  Not related but that did fix the comma placement.  =P